# Start text terminal shell from Linux DM?

Tags: login, desktop-environment, profile, gdm

Is it possible to start a shell in a text terminal from a Linux Desktop Manager such as GDM, MDM or KDM?

I have a user that has a .profile with a bash select loop offering the option to startx (where the relevent stuff is in .xinitrc), and an option to start a shell with text console. I am wondering if this user could still use the DM to start a shell session (and startx manually if need be like I said before)?

I've already tried creating a xsessions/bash.desktop file with exec=/bin/bash, but that didn't work...

(EDITED for clarity)

EDIT:
Also, if this is not the case with the DMs I mentioned above, Is there one that would allow this, or even a graphical login manager that doesn't use .desktop files at all and is designed to log a user in (only) and leave starting xorg (again) to the user?

Comment: Okay, I'll still happily accept answers to this question, but in the meantime I'm going to poke around the ArchWiki, specifically https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_manager ... SLiM seems like it might work the way I want it to.

Comment: Check out [CDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CDM) which is a display manager written in shell-script.